# PoolMon displaying insane numbers

Tags: windows, windows-10

While debugging a memory leak, I came to a rather interesting finding:

[image]

The lower pools do add up to the number shown in Task Manager, so this insane number (~440GB) *seems* to be bogus (owned by volsnap.sys - Volume Shadow Copy).

I couldn't find this as all google results are about the memory leaks themselves.

**The question**: is this just a bug in poolmon/kernel/something else or is there actually a reason for this?

PC specs and a bit of config, if relevant:
i7-4710MQ,
16GB RAM @ 1600MHz,
256GB SSD (C:), 1TB (D:, E:) and 250GB (Z:) HDDs,
Win10 Pro, build 10240,
File History set up for some folders in C: and D: into Z:.

Comment: do you use the 32Bit poolmon on a 64Bit Windows? Maybe this causes some overflows.

Comment: am using the one from \Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64, task manager shows no (32 bit) tag, so no. In addition, 32bit integers fit only ~4.3E9 values, and 64bit ~1.8E19 values, with this being 'only' 4.4E11 - IMO unlikely to be a simple overflow.

Comment: tr to capture some of the usage grow with xperf/WPA (use the Win10 WPT from Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk): https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-48-WPT-Memory-Analysis-Pool

Comment: please mind that the memory leak is not in (this) question, and poolmon shows only 2 allocations and 1 freeing of this size, not much growth to be seen

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  I did not mean for this to be posted as an answer as it is not.  I also just realized I cannot comment on original thread.  Not sure what my options are.

---

I'm having this same issue.  Started troubleshooting a memory leak myself and PoolMon is showing one tag with astronomical value, but for different tag than your own and my number is far larger.  I'm also on Windows 10 x64.

The tag in mine is B1L6 (not sure what that is yet), and the value is 562949953421312 bytes, which translates to 563 Tbytes (which is impossible on my machine).

Not sure what's up here.

[image: PoolMon Massive Paged Pool]